# SonarQube: Get all Issues of a particular user

Tags: version-control, sonarqube

I am able to get the name of the developer who committed the culprit line when directly viewing the file, but is it possible to get all issues of a particular developer in a central location?

The email address the developer uses to log in to the system is the same as that of the SCM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest issue page (on version 5.1 of SonarQube) you can search issues by author. Just click on Issues in the top bar and select the author facet. Have [a look on nemo](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/issues/search#resolved=false%7Cauthors=nicolas.peru%40sonarsource.com) to see this feature (and all my issues ;) )